# Datatables how do I sort this table correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables-1.10

My datatable is not sorting correctly. I think the problem is related to the decimal values as there is no consistency in them.
What is the best way to sort this correctly?
Do I need a special plugin for this?
Any help/advice appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Please see code below. Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#abc').DataTable( {
   columnDefs: [
       { type: 'natural', targets: 0 }
     ],
  responsive: true,
  
   
  bSort: true,   
   order: []
} );

  } );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<body>
<table id="abc"  style="width: 100%;"><thead>

<tr>
<th style=" width: 25%;">abcd</th>

</tr>

</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td> 1.2</td>


<tr>
<td> 3.001</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td> 8.1025</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td> 40</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td> 41</td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td> 180</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td> 205</td>




</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTables default is to sort as text. If you want to sort numerically, you need to specify that in your `columnDefs`.

You can set your column type as a `num`, as described here:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#abc').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            type: 'num',
            targets: 0
        }],
        responsive: true,


        bSort: true,
        order: []
    });

});
```

Comment: sorting doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: sorry, it worked!!